# Can the Tour be Improved?

Tags: feature-request, questions

I repeatedly find the same problems with questions, particularly (but not exclusively) from new users:

- No model #s listed - just "a new dimmer" or "a new light fixture", etc. With model #s, which are always (well, perhaps except for some really junky stuff...) available for the new items (not as often for the old item being replaced), it is often very easy to find installation instructions online to answer the question. The OP may not understand the instructions (which is why they are asking a question, unless they simply *ignored* the instructions, which is a different problem) but there is usually someone more experienced who can decipher the instructions and solve the problem. But not without knowing the model #.
- Country not clear. Recently there was one that sounded (based on 120V) like US, but then threw in some French references and that raised the "are you in Europe" question. It turns out this was French Canadian, but knowing the country is very important for electrical questions and often for plumbing or other types of questions too.
- Pictures. A lot of new people don't know how to upload pictures. But pictures are often critical to figuring out problems (especially plumbing and electrical). The tour doesn't say anything about how to upload pictures.

Can we add two sections to the Tour?

- DIY-specific information for asking questions. Model #, country as I mentioned, and others may have some additional things to include.
- A brief summary of how to upload pictures, or at least a one-liner with a link. This would be useful for **ALL** StackExchange sites.

And finally, one part I can't easily check without making up another user (and I really don't like doing that). What, if any, notification is given to new users about the Tour? A number of people (including myself occasionally) will comment on a new post "Take the Tour". Ideally, in addition to (as I hope there already is but can't remember), new users being prompted to take the Tour after initial registration, I think it would make sense to prompt any not-yet-taken-the-tour-user to take the Tour when they start to ask a question. Just an extra click to either "take the Tour" or to "ask a question right away".

Comment: The only parts that the Tour [can be customized by mods are](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259920/241919): The introduction paragraph, the example question, and the on/off-topic list; the instruction to upload a picture in the Tour needs SE dev (and most of the time, images aren't necessary to make questions clear on other sites). Also, new *registered* users get the [Tour notification on email and inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/305964/241919). The real problem is... usually they choose to ignore it.

Comment: @AndrewT. Thanks for that information. The last part of the "can be customized by mods are" answer that you linked includes info. (which I have verified is still the case) that was customized for codegolf questions. I think that would be a great solution here. Any idea how we can get that done?

Comment: Well, for that case, the meta is indeed the correct place to request that (like ["How to Answer" popup on Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7070/lets-customise-the-how-to-answer-pop-up)). But as mentioned on that meta post, you really need to provide compelling reasons, because Code Golf is an exceptional case of using SE's Q&A platform for non-Q&A purpose.

Comment: @AndrewT. I hope anyone who looked at the comments on a very high percentage of DIY questions of "what model" and "where are you located" and "add some pictures" would agree that making these changes would be helpful. When I (ha ha ha) have a little time I'll draft a possible text.